# Spark - Creating Nested DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm starting with PySpark and I'm having troubles with creating DataFrames with nested objects.

This is my example.

I have users.

```
$ cat user.json
{"id":1,"name":"UserA"}
{"id":2,"name":"UserB"}
```

Users have orders.

```
$ cat order.json
{"id":1,"price":202.30,"userid":1}
{"id":2,"price":343.99,"userid":1}
{"id":3,"price":399.99,"userid":2}
```

And I like to join it to get such a struct where orders are array nested in users.

```
$ cat join.json
{"id":1, "name":"UserA", "orders":[{"id":1,"price":202.30,"userid":1},{"id":2,"price":343.99,"userid":1}]}
{"id":2,"name":"UserB","orders":[{"id":3,"price":399.99,"userid":2}]}
```

How can I do that ?
Is there any kind of nested join or something similar ?

```
>>> user = sqlContext.read.json("user.json")
>>> user.printSchema();
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

>>> order =  sqlContext.read.json("order.json")
>>> order.printSchema();
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- userid: long (nullable = true)

>>> joined = sqlContext.read.json("join.json")
>>> joined.printSchema();
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- orders: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- userid: long (nullable = true)
```

EDIT:
I know there is possibility to do this using join and foldByKey, but is there any simpler way ?

EDIT2:
I'm using solution by @zero323

```
def joinTable(tableLeft, tableRight, columnLeft, columnRight, columnNested, joinType = "left_outer"):
    tmpTable = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(tableRight.rdd.groupBy(lambda r: r.asDict()[columnRight]))
    tmpTable = tmpTable.select(tmpTable._1.alias("joinColumn"), tmpTable._2.data.alias(columnNested))
    return tableLeft.join(tmpTable, tableLeft[columnLeft] == tmpTable["joinColumn"], joinType).drop("joinColumn")
```

I add second nested structure 'lines'

```
>>> lines =  sqlContext.read.json(path + "lines.json")
>>> lines.printSchema();
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- orderid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- product: string (nullable = true)

orders = joinTable(order, lines, "id", "orderid", "lines")
joined = joinTable(user, orders, "id", "userid", "orders")
joined.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- orders: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- userid: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lines: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _3: string (nullable = true)
```

After this column names from lines are lost.
Any ideas ?

EDIT 3:
I tried to manual specify schema.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
fields = []
fields.append(StructField("_1", LongType(), True))
inner = ArrayType(lines.schema)
fields.append(StructField("_2", inner))
new_schema = StructType(fields)
print new_schema

grouped =  lines.rdd.groupBy(lambda r: r.orderid)
grouped =  grouped.map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1])))
g = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(grouped, new_schema)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: StructType(List(StructField(id,LongType,true),StructField(orderid,LongType,true),StructField(product,StringType,true))) can not accept object in type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**This will work only in Spark 2.0 or later**

First we'll need a couple of imports:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, collect_list
```

The rest is a simple aggregation and join:

```py
orders = spark.read.json("/path/to/order.json")
users = spark.read.json("/path/to/user.json")

combined = users.join(
    orders
        .groupBy("userId")
        .agg(collect_list(struct(*orders.columns)).alias("orders"))
        .withColumnRenamed("userId", "id"), ["id"])
```

For the example data the result is:

```py
combined.show(2, False)
```

```
+---+-----+---------------------------+
|id |name |orders                     |
+---+-----+---------------------------+
|1  |UserA|[[1,202.3,1], [2,343.99,1]]|
|2  |UserB|[[3,399.99,2]]             |
+---+-----+---------------------------+
```

with schema:

```py
combined.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- orders: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- userid: long (nullable = true)
```

and JSON representation:

```py
for x in combined.toJSON().collect():
    print(x)
```

```
{"id":1,"name":"UserA","orders":[{"id":1,"price":202.3,"userid":1},{"id":2,"price":343.99,"userid":1}]}
{"id":2,"name":"UserB","orders":[{"id":3,"price":399.99,"userid":2}]}
```

Comment: Note that the reason that this works is that even though users is a large (since its in a dataframe), the number of orders for a particular user is small enough to be held in a collection.  What if that were not the case?  What if the orders were something else say for the sake of argument, users with the same hair color, that can't be held in a collection?  Would you be forced to collect the hair colors and go through them serially, or could you possibly use a cartesian join?

Comment: @oneirois In short - the whole idea won't be viable. Row is the minimal unit of parallelism and cannot be divided or partially spilled. You could just use `DataFrameWriter` to have separate file for each grouping factor without creating a nested structure - this would scale much better.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing :)

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to use the `userid` as the join key for the second `DataFrame`:

```
user.join(order, user.id == order.userid)
```

Then you can use a `map` step to transform the resulting records to your desired format.

Comment: Not really. `Map` is not enough. 
If I join users and orders I will have 3 records. (and I want only 2). So I also need some kind of aggregation (foldByKey for example)

Answer (score -1):

**For flatining your data frame from nested to normal use**

`dff= df.select("column with multiple columns.*")`

Comment: Don't use Pandas please ! This will calls a Spark collect() ! It's very slow and not distributed because all the data will brought back to a single point which is the Spark driver.