# pyspark: join tables based on nested keys

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables with the below example schemas. The keys for table A are nested in a list in table B. I would like to join table A and table B based on the table A keys to generate table C. The values from table A should be a nested structure in table C based on the list of keyAs in table B. How can I do this using pyspark? Thanks!

Table A

```
root 
|-- item1: string (nullable = true) 
|-- item2: long (nullable = true) 
|-- keyA: string (nullable = true)
```

Table B

```
root 
|-- item1: string (nullable = true) 
|-- item2: long (nullable = true) 
|-- keyB: string (nullable = true) 
|-- keyAs: array (nullable = true) 
| |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Table C

```
root 
|-- item1: string (nullable = true) 
|-- item2: long (nullable = true) 
|-- keyB: string (nullable = true) 
|-- keyAs: array (nullable = true) 
| |-- element: string (containsNull = true) 
|-- valueAs: array (nullable = true) 
| |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
| | |-- item1: string (nullable = true) 
| | |-- item2: long (nullable = true) 
| | |-- keyA: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

For joining A and B you need to explode `B.keyAs` first, like this:

```
tableB.withColumn('keyA', explode('keyAs')).join(tableA, 'keyA')
```

For creating a nested structure please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41091625/7098262)