# PySpark Dataframe Transpose as List

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with pyspark sql api, and trying to group rows with repeated values into a list of rest of contents.  It's similar to transpose, but instead of pivoting all values, will put values into array.

Current output:

```
group_id | member_id | name
55       | 123       | jake
55       | 234       | tim 
65       | 345       | chris
```

Desired output:

```
group_id | members
55       | [[123, 'jake'], [234, 'tim']]
65       | [345, 'chris']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark - Creating Nested DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919371/spark-creating-nested-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `groupby` the `group_id` and use [`pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) as the aggregation function.

As for combining the `member_id` and `name` columns, you have two options:

#### Option 1: Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.array`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, collect_list

df1 = df.groupBy("group_id")\
    .agg(collect_list(array("member_id", "name")).alias("members"))

df1.show(truncate=False)
#+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
#|group_id|members                                          |
#+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
#|55      |[WrappedArray(123, jake), WrappedArray(234, tim)]|
#|65      |[WrappedArray(345, chris)]                       |
#+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

This returns a `WrappedArray` of arrays of strings. The integers are converted to strings because you can't have mixed type arrays.

```python
df1.printSchema()
#root
# |-- group_id: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- members: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

#### Option 2: Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.struct`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct)

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, struct 

df2 = df.groupBy("group_id")\
    .agg(collect_list(struct("member_id", "name")).alias("members"))

df2.show(truncate=False)
#+--------+-----------------------+
#|group_id|members                |
#+--------+-----------------------+
#|65      |[[345,chris]]          |
#|55      |[[123,jake], [234,tim]]|
#+--------+-----------------------+
```

This returns an array of structs, with named fields for `member_id` and `name`

```python
df2.printSchema()
#root
# |-- group_id: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- members: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- member_id: integer (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

What's useful about the struct method is that you can access elements of the nested array by name using the dot accessor:

```python
df2.select("group_id", "members.member_id").show()
#+--------+----------+
#|group_id| member_id|
#+--------+----------+
#|      65|     [345]|
#|      55|[123, 234]|
#+--------+----------+
```