# How to convert flatten data frame into nested JSON using spark and scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to convert a flatten data frame into a nested Json file , please find the example below.

my df will look like below-
shop_id mng_number  item_id variant_id  dual_price_id   regular_price
123    vj123        456    vj123-red    1                1222222
123    vj123        456    vj123-green  1                238000

and result i will be looking for would look like below-
{
"shop_id":123,
"mng_number":"vj123",
"item_id":456,
"vj":{
"vj123-red": {
"dual_price_id":1,
"regular_price":1222222
},
"vj123-green": {
"dual_price_id":1,
"regular_price":238000
}
}
}

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919371/spark-creating-nested-dataframe

Comment: do you have solution in scala?

Comment: Syntax will be similar.

Comment: able to achieve data , but and extra [] comes with subdata, can you please help with it

Comment: able to achieve data , but and extra [] comes with subdata, can you please help with it-
as-is:
{"shop_id":"1","variants":[{"sku3":{"dual_price_id":-9999,"result":1}},{"sku2":{"dual_price_id":-9999,"result":1}}]}
    {"shop_id":"1","variants":[{"sku10":{"dual_price_id":-9999,"result":1}},{"sku3":{"dual_price_id":-9999,"result":1}}]}

to-be:
{"shop_id":"1","variants":{"sku3":{"dual_price_id":-9999,"result":1}},{"sku2":{"dual_price_id":-9999,"result":1}}}
    {"shop_id":"1","variants":{"sku10":{"dual_price_id":-9999,"result":1}},{"sku3":{"dual_price_id":-9999,"result":1}}}

Comment: it's because 'variants' is an array. You can explode it with the help for 'explode' commands. Check it - https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/explode-spark-array-and-map-dataframe-column/

Comment: @AleksejsR I dnt want it to be exploded , i need it in json format but not Array-
{"shop_id":"1","variants":{"sku3":{"dual_price_id":-9999,"result":1},"sku2":{"dual_price_id":-9999,"result":1}}}